# Collectd not collecting data when changed to "High Counter" or HC OIDs in snmp plugin config

Tags: collectd

I am playing with collectd. Evertying works fine until I decided to use "ifHCInOctets" instead of "ifInOctets". Here is my SNMP plugin config.

```
<Plugin snmp>
    <Data "std_traffic_hc">
            Type "if_octets"
            Table true
#           Instance "IF-MIB::ifDescr"
            Instance "IF-MIB::ifName"
#           Values "IF-MIB::ifInOctets" "IF-MIB::ifOutOctets"
            Values "IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets" "IF-MIB::ifHCOutOctets"
    </Data>
    <Host "ABCDESW01-01">
            Address "10.0.3.131"
            Version 1
            Community "xxx"
            Collect "std_traffic_hc"
            Interval 60
    </Host>
</Plugin>
```

I have also tried ifDescr and ifName in the "Instance" directive and that did not make a difference. Either one works for the regular OID but not the HC OID.

I used tcpdump but I don't see collectd ever tried to send snmp traffic to the HC OID. I do see the snmp traffic for the Instance OID.

I have also used snmpwalk to confirm that my switch (HP) supports the OID:

```
# snmpwalk -v2c -cxxx 10.0.3.131 IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.1 = Counter64: 0
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.2 = Counter64: 356053022
```

Where did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well High Counter OID aren't usable within SNMP v1 so i would guess that that's the problem here.

You are correctly manually requesting the OID in Version 2c on the CLI, but the collectd configuration is set to "Version 1"

Comment: Thank you Silmaril! As soon as I changed the version number to 2 under my "host" definition it all works fine now!